# Geodesic on a plane using parametric equations

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

I'm trying to solve the geodesic problem on a plane using the parametrization $x=x(t), y=y(t), x'=\frac{dx}{dt}, y'=\frac{dy}{dt}$.

But when using the Euler-Lagrange equation, I'm obtaining that

$$ -\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{x'}{\sqrt{x'^2 +y'^2}} \right]-\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{y'}{\sqrt{x'^2 +y'^2}} \right]=0$$

where I've been stuck since I can't find the solution to obtain the straight line equation.

Comment: Can you detail your geodesic problem here ?

Comment: Obtain the shortest distance between two points in the Euclidean xy-plane, using the parametrization $x=x(t),y=y(t)$. The arc length is given by the integral of the square root of the sum of the derivatives of x and y squared, that is: $\int \sqrt{(x')^2 + (y')^2}$. The Euler-Lagrange equations are given by: $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}- \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}- \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} $, where L is the Lagrangian defined as $L= \sqrt{(x')^2+(y')^2} $

Comment: You’d better review the E-L equations! Note the *s*.

Comment: @TedShifrin those are the E-L equations that our professor gave us in the course; if you could recommend a specific textbook or reference material, it would be appreciated. Also, what $s$ are you referring to?

Comment: You should have two separate equation*s* here. There are lots of standard texts. In the setting of elementary differential geometry, I have a section (the last one) in my differential geometry text, freely linked in my profile, which might help you.

Comment: @TedShifrin Our professor told us to "split" the equations (we aren't following the course with so much formality), so we could have a system of equations given by $-\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{x'}{\sqrt{x'^2 +y'^2}} \right]=0 $ and $ -\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{y'}{\sqrt{x'^2 +y'^2}} \right]=0$. If those are the equations you are referring to, could you help me with the main issue I'm strugglin with: finding a way to solve those equations to eventually obtain the straight line equation?

Comment: Well, what you posted certainly wasn't correct. This tells you that both coordinates of the unit tangent vector of the curve are constant, i.e., that the unit tangent vector is constant. That gives you a line. If you assume an arclength parametrization (so that $x'^2+y'^2=1$), then you get just $x'$, $y'$ constant, and you can certainly integrate explicitly to get the parametric equations of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler-Lagrange equations tell you in this case that

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'})$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'})$$

For the Lagrangian $L(x', y')=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}$, the derivatives on the left hand side of the equations are zero. Integrating both sides with respect to $t$ then yields

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'} = A$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} = B$$

Where $A, B$ are constants. Now, we can plug in our Lagrangian, take the derivatives, and get

$$\frac{2x'}{2\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}} = A \implies 2\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2} = \frac{2x'}{A}$$
$$\frac{2y'}{2\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}} = B \implies 2\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2} = \frac{2y'}{B}$$

Combining the equations gives

$$\frac{2x'}{A}=\frac{2y'}{B} \implies y'=\frac{B}{A}x'$$

Finally, we can integrate both sides with respect to $t$, and conclude

$$y = \frac{B}{A}x +C$$

Which is obviously a line (it is of the form $y = mx+b$).